# Detect vulnerability based on IIS log

Tags: vulnerability, server, logging, iis

Is there any tools to detect website vulnerability/suspicious request from IIS log?
I was asked to do log review. The logs include IIS Log and Event Log. Is there any tools to detect if there's any issue on the app / server from the log ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you cannot put a WAF in front of your server for exactly this?

Answer (score 1):

As I assume you want a monitoring tool beside the WAF, there are two well-known tools for this purpose:

1. ManageEngine event log analyzer
2. Nagios IIS log monitoring